# Using an HDFS Sink and rollInterval in Flume-ng to batch up 90 seconds of log information

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am trying to use Flume-ng to grab 90 seconds of log information and put it into a file in HDFS.  I have flume working to look at the log file via an exec and tail however it is creating a file every 5 seconds instead of what I am trying to configure as every 90 seconds.

My flume.conf is as follows:

```
# example.conf: A single-node Flume configuration                                                                                                                  
# Name the components on this agent                                                                                                                                
agent1.sources = source1
agent1.sinks = sink1
agent1.channels = channel1

# Describe/configure source1                                                                                                                                       
agent1.sources.source1.type = exec
agent1.sources.source1.command = tail -f /home/cloudera/LogCreator/fortune_log.log

# Describe sink1                                                                                                                                                   
agent1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = LogCreateTest
# this parameter seems to be getting overridden                                                                                                                    
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval=90
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize=0
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.hdfs.rollCount = 0

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory                                                                                                                     
agent1.channels.channel1.type = memory

# Bind the source and sink to the channel                                                                                                                          
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

I am attempting to control the file size by the parameter - **agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval=90**.

Running this config produces:

```
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:/etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
13/01/03 09:43:02 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: sink1 Agent: agent1
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration  for agents: [agent1]
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1, registered successfully.
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: created channel channel1
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: sink1, type: hdfs
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Hadoop Security enabled: false
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitoried counter group for type: SINK, name: sink1, registered successfully.
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{source1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource{name:source1,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{sink1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@1a50ca0c counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{channel1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: channel1}} }
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting Channel channel1
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: channel1 started
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting Sink sink1
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager: Starting Source source1
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: sink1 started
13/01/03 09:43:03 INFO source.ExecSource: Exec source starting with command:tail -f /home/cloudera/LogCreator/fortune_log.log
13/01/03 09:43:07 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest//LogCreateTest.1357224186506.tmp
13/01/03 09:43:08 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186506.tmp to hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186506
13/01/03 09:43:08 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest//LogCreateTest.1357224186507.tmp
13/01/03 09:43:12 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186507.tmp to hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186507
13/01/03 09:43:12 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest//LogCreateTest.1357224186508.tmp
13/01/03 09:43:12 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186508.tmp to hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186508
13/01/03 09:43:12 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest//LogCreateTest.1357224186509.tmp
13/01/03 09:43:18 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186509.tmp to hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186509
13/01/03 09:43:18 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest//LogCreateTest.1357224186510.tmp
13/01/03 09:43:18 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186510.tmp to hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/LogCreateTest.1357224186510
```

As you can see by the timestamps it is creating a file about every 5 seconds or so.  This creates to many small files.

I would like to be able to create the file on a larger time interval (90 seconds).

Answer (score 3):

A rewrite of the config file specifying a more complete selection of parameters did the trick.  This example will write after 10k records or 10 min which ever comes first.  In addition I changed from a memory channel to a file channel to aid in reliability on the data flow.

```
agent1.sources = source1
agent1.sinks = sink1
agent1.channels = channel1

# Describe/configure source1                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
agent1.sources.source1.type = exec
agent1.sources.source1.command = tail -f /home/cloudera/LogCreator/fortune_log.log

# Describe sink1                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
agent1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost/flume/logtest/
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = LogCreateTest
# Number of seconds to wait before rolling current file (0 = never roll based on time interval)                                                                                                                                              
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
# File size to trigger roll, in bytes (0: never roll based on file size)                                                                                                                                                                     
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
#Number of events written to file before it rolled (0 = never roll based on number of events)                                                                                                                                                
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
# number of events written to file before it flushed to HDFS                                                                                                                                                                                 
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.txnEventMax = 40000
# -- Compression codec. one of following : gzip, bzip2, lzo, snappy                                                                                                                                                                          
# hdfs.codeC = gzip                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#format: currently SequenceFile, DataStream or CompressedStream                                                                                                                                                                              
#(1)DataStream will not compress output file and please don't set codeC                                                                                                                                                                      
#(2)CompressedStream requires set hdfs.codeC with an available codeC                                                                                                                                                                         
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles=50
# -- "Text" or "Writable"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#hdfs.writeFormat                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.appendTimeout = 10000
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.callTimeout = 10000
# Number of threads per HDFS sink for HDFS IO ops (open, write, etc.)                                                                                                                                                                        
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.threadsPoolSize=100
# Number of threads per HDFS sink for scheduling timed file rolling                                                                                                                                                                          
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollTimerPoolSize = 1
# hdfs.kerberosPrin--cipal Kerberos user principal for accessing secure HDFS                                                                                                                                                                 
# hdfs.kerberosKey--tab Kerberos keytab for accessing secure HDFS                                                                                                                                                                            
# hdfs.round false Should the timestamp be rounded down (if true, affects all time based escape sequences except %t)                                                                                                                         
# hdfs.roundValue1 Rounded down to the highest multiple of this (in the unit configured using                                                                                                                                                
# hdfs.roundUnit), less than current time.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# hdfs.roundUnit second The unit of the round down value - second, minute or hour.                                                                                                                                                           
# serializer TEXT Other possible options include AVRO_EVENT or the fully-qualified class name of an implementation of the EventSerializer.Builder interface.                                                                                 
# serializer.*                                                                                                                                                                                                                               


# Use a channel which buffers events to a file                                                                                                                                                                                               
# -- The component type name, needs to be FILE.                                                                                                                                                                                              
agent1.channels.channel1.type = FILE
# checkpointDir ~/.flume/file-channel/checkpoint The directory where checkpoint file will be stored                                                                                                                                          
# dataDirs ~/.flume/file-channel/data The directory where log files will be stored                                                                                                                                                           
# The maximum size of transaction supported by the channel                                                                                                                                                                                   
agent1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000000
# Amount of time (in millis) between checkpoints                                                                                                                                                                                             
agent1.channels.channel1.checkpointInterval 30000
# Max size (in bytes) of a single log file                                                                                                                                                                                                   
agent1.channels.channel1.maxFileSize = 2146435071
# Maximum capacity of the channel                                                                                                                                                                                                            
agent1.channels.channel1.capacity 10000000
#keep-alive 3 Amount of time (in sec) to wait for a put operation                                                                                                                                                                            
#write-timeout 3 Amount of time (in sec) to wait for a write operation                                                                                                                                                                       

# Bind the source and sink to the channel                                                                                                                                                                                                    
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code of org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter:

```
 /**
 * Internal API intended for HDFSSink use.
 * This class does file rolling and handles file formats and serialization.
 * Only the public methods in this class are thread safe.
 */
class BucketWriter {
  ...
  /**
   * open() is called by append()
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws InterruptedException
   */
  private void open() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ...
    // if time-based rolling is enabled, schedule the roll
    if (rollInterval > 0) {
      Callable<Void> action = new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
          LOG.debug("Rolling file ({}): Roll scheduled after {} sec elapsed.",
              bucketPath, rollInterval);
          try {
            // Roll the file and remove reference from sfWriters map.
            close(true);
          } catch(Throwable t) {
            LOG.error("Unexpected error", t);
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
      timedRollFuture = timedRollerPool.schedule(action, rollInterval,
          TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
   /**
   * check if time to rotate the file
   */
  private boolean shouldRotate() {
    boolean doRotate = false;

    if (writer.isUnderReplicated()) {
      this.isUnderReplicated = true;
      doRotate = true;
    } else {
      this.isUnderReplicated = false;
    }

    if ((rollCount > 0) && (rollCount <= eventCounter)) {
      LOG.debug("rolling: rollCount: {}, events: {}", rollCount, eventCounter);
      doRotate = true;
    }

    if ((rollSize > 0) && (rollSize <= processSize)) {
      LOG.debug("rolling: rollSize: {}, bytes: {}", rollSize, processSize);
      doRotate = true;
    }

    return doRotate;
  }
...
}
```

and org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AbstractHDFSWriter

```
public abstract class AbstractHDFSWriter implements HDFSWriter {
...
  @Override
  public boolean isUnderReplicated() {
    try {
      int numBlocks = getNumCurrentReplicas();
      if (numBlocks == -1) {
        return false;
      }
      int desiredBlocks;
      if (configuredMinReplicas != null) {
        desiredBlocks = configuredMinReplicas;
      } else {
        desiredBlocks = getFsDesiredReplication();
      }
      return numBlocks < desiredBlocks;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      logger.error("Unexpected error while checking replication factor", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      logger.error("Unexpected error while checking replication factor", e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      logger.error("Unexpected error while checking replication factor", e);
    }
    return false;
  }
...
}
```

the rolling of hdfs files is controlled by 4 conditions:

1. hdfs.rollSize
2. hdfs.rollCount
3. hdfs.minBlockReplicas(highest priority, but usually not the reason causing rolling small file)
4. hdfs.rollInterval

Change the values accoding to these if-segments in BucketWriter.class