# Flume Twitter Stream rolling small files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, twitter4j, flume

I think I have tried every combination of altering my config file. I also saw somewhere that it might be due to my replication factor being 3 so I changed it to 1. I am using cloudera manager on AWS. Below is my config file, any ideas?

In HDFS, the file sizes are all under 20kb, trying to get at least 40-50mb. What is funny is that the same config file is writing ~60mb files on my virtual machine that I was practicing with (pre-installed hadoop + tools). See  below for config file, any ideas?

```
# The configuration file needs to define the sources, 
# the channels and the sinks.
# Sources, channels and sinks are defined per agent, 
# in this case called 'TwitterAgent'

TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = apple, grapes, fruits, strawberry, mango, pear
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://123.456.789.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8020/user/flume/tweets
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 100000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

Comment: Have you checked this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145899/flume-hdfs-sink-keeps-rolling-small-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured out the issue. (note I am running a single node test cluster).  One of the solutions in stackoverflow was to set the dfs.replication factor to 1 which I did but that did not solve the problem.

For some reason what was happening was that in my flume agent, there was a mismatch in configs. The HDFS Sink has a parameter called `minBlockReplicas`, which informs it as to how many block replicas are necessary to have, and if not specified, it pulls that paramaneter from the default HDFS configuration file (which i thought I set to 1). It looks like it was getting a different value for `dfs.replication` or for `dfs.namennode.replication.min`.

I circumvented the error my modifying my flume file directly by using

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.minBlockReplicas = 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If `rollInterval`, `batchSize`, `rollSize` & `rollCount` are not working, remain things looks `hdfs.callTimeout`.

Because someone said reducing replication factor could be solution.

Reducing replication factor means reducing `hdfs` operation time and according to flume user [guideline](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink), default value of `callTimeout` is 10000 milliseconds.

Other clues are

- [How-to: Do Apache Flume Performance Tuning (Part 1)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-do-apache-flume-performance-tuning-part-1/)
- [How can I force Flume-NG to process the backlog of events after a sink failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613761/how-can-i-force-flume-ng-to-process-the-backlog-of-events-after-a-sink-failed)
- [Using an HDFS Sink and rollInterval in Flume-ng to batch up 90 seconds of log information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141287/using-an-hdfs-sink-and-rollinterval-in-flume-ng-to-batch-up-90-seconds-of-log-in)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, by adding this line it is resolved my small multiple files creating on HDFS while using flume

```
a1.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.minBlockReplicas = 1
```

Comment: please don't add works-for-too comments as answers - once you'll have enough reputation you can upvote/comment the other answer :-)